# Is Corda's gradle version requirement a minimum?

Tags: corda

Part of the upgrade steps for moving to Corda open source 4.3 are to use Gradle 5.4.1 https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.3/app-upgrade-notes.html#step-2-update-gradle-version-and-associated-dependencies

Does Corda require this precise version of Gradle or can a later version be used. For example: could 5.6.4 be used instead?

If later versions of Gradle can be used how can developers know what maximum version of Gradle is compatible with Corda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Gradle 5.6.4 with Corda, although nothing higher as the Gradle plugin for Kotlin 1.2.71 is incompatible with Gradle 6.x.

Corda is currently constrained to use Kotlin 1.2.x both by its dependence on Quasar and by a change to Kotlin byte-code that was introduced in Kotlin 1.3.40. We are working to resolve this.